# Switch statement error with Static integers

Tags: java, static, switch-statement

Why am I getting " } " error in switch statment below. I don't see any syntax error.
I don't get error on compiling the code. Eclipse is indicating error at the specified position below.

After putting } I get this error

```
- The static field KeyEvent.VK_XXXX should be accessed in a 
 static way
- case expressions must be constant expressions

switch(event.getKeyCode())
        {
        case event.VK_BACK_SLASH:
            backColor=but[27].getBackground();
            break;

        case event.VK_RIGHT:
            for(int i=0;i<but.length;i++)
            {
                if(" > ".equals(but[i].getText()))
                {
                    backColor=but[i].getBackground();
                    break;
                }
            }
            break; // error here
   }
```

When I press the key, I get the follwoing error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete SwitchBlock

    at Keyboard$HandlerClass.keyPressed(Keyboard.java:242) // this is break statement


    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
```

Regards

Comment: post the text of the error, that might give as a better idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I could see in your code is the following (but it's not a compiletime/runtime error), which most probably would end up as a bug:

```
but[i].getText() == " > " //this is called object identity check
```

That's not the right way to compare strings. Use `.equals` method instead

```
" > ".equals(but[i].getText()) //this is object equality check
```

**Update**

> The static field KeyEvent.VK_XXXX should be accessed in a static way

That means you should change `event.VK_BACK_SLASH` to `KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH`, ...

Comment: Just want to repeat Rohit's comment, what's the exact error? You can post the stacktrace itself.

Comment: @Bhesh: thats all well and good but it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: I am not getting error while compilation, eclipse is showing cross sign where I indicated

Comment: @SurenderThakran: That's why I mentioned that it's not a compiletime/runtime error.

Comment: @Alfred: You probably just need a save and quick build then.

Comment: Thanks alot sir. but why " . ".contentEquals(but[i].getText()) not giving any response

Comment: It's not `.contentEquals`, just `.equals`. "... not giving any response.", I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

**To solve any compile issues:**

Firstly use the class name to refer static content instead of the object reference. Meaning, in the case statements use KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH instead of event.VK_BACK_SLASH

If that does not work out, I suspect there is an error in some other part of your program may be you are not having the right number of matching braces. A simple grep should help you identify the problem. Try grep "{" | wc -l AND grep "}" | wc -l.

**To root cause your run-time problem:**

Try running it outside the scope of eclipse. Either by adding the root directory to the class path or packaging the class files into a jar file.

Answer (score 0):

The error `The static field KeyEvent.VK_XXXX should be accessed in a static way` means what it says: you should access the fields statically, like so:

```
case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH:
    // Do something
    break;
case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
    // Do something else
    break;
```